# invalid user: ‘root:root' performing chown

Tags: linux, permissions

I was using SSHFS for mounting remote FS (CentOS 7) to my work PC when I performed: 
`sudo chown user:user /mnt/mountpoin`
Since remote FS looks like this:

```
dr-xr-xr-x.   6 0 0  1024 июл 21  2017 boot
drwxr-xr-x   21 0 0  3400 сен 15  2017 dev
drwxr-xr-x. 107 0 0 12288 апр 13 12:58 etc
drwxr-xr-x.   4 0 0  4096 апр 13 12:58 home
lrwxrwxrwx.   1 0 0     7 июн  6  2017 lib -> usr/lib
lrwxrwxrwx.   1 0 0     9 июн  6  2017 lib64 -> usr/lib64
drwx------.   2 0 0 16384 июн  6  2017 lost+found
```

And when I try change owner to root to any directories or files I see error: `invalid user: ‘root:root'`. I realize first I should get back access to `/etc/passwd` to root but I really can't understand how to do it...

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to restore server. 
For this purpose I booted to Emergency Mode thru GRUB boot menu. So filesystem was mounted in read-only and I was able to login as root. Further, I remounted fs in read-write mode (mount -o remount,rw /) and change owner of root directory to root (chmod root:root /). In my case owner of root directory had id 1000. Subdirs had properly owner.